# Getting JSON values by order and keeping the corresponding names in order

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I currently have some JSON data like the following:

```
{"data": [
    {"student_id": "bobby", "solved": 19},
    {"student_id": "smith", "solved": 20}
]}
```

Now what I am doing right now is pushing the solved values into an array called `newData` in a for loop like the following:

```
newData.push(data['data'][i].solved);
```

Now I sort these by values by using this function:

```
newData.sort(function(a,b){
    return a-b;        
});
```

Great, now I have an array of values in order. But how can I retrieve the names which correspond to these values which I sorted in order? It would be nice if I could have the names and solved in two arrays, but each index corresponds to the same in the original JSON data. One huge array with objects and values sorted is ok too I guess.

Comment: That isn't JSON. JSON is a formatted *string*. That is an array of JavaScript objects. The difference is not trivial.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first sort data by `solved` key and then use `map()` to return two separate arrays of results in sorted order.

```js
var obj = {"data": [{"student_id": "bobby", "solved": 19}, {"student_id": "smith", "solved": 20}]}

var newData = obj.data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.solved - a.solved;
});

var numbers = newData.map(e => e.solved);
var names =  newData.map(e => e.student_id);

console.log(numbers);
console.log(names);
```

Comment: Why data.data? Sorry that just looks a bit confusing to me

Comment: That is just name of var you can use anything.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with =>, I havent studied this yet, I'll try looking it up and learning it. In the meantime is there anything I can replace the => with?

Comment: That is ES6 arrow functions you can use regular functions https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1075/

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll look on mozilla for more examples. Since that is ES6, should I still use it, even though it might not work on some browsers? Just wondering if this is good form (I'm pretty new to js)

Comment: I used it in this demo for simplicity but you can go with regular functions, you can find browser support at the end of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just sort the actual objects?

```
json.data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.solved - b.solved;        
});
```

Now you have a sorted array of objects. If you want the lowest student, just use `sorted[0].student_id`. You can see how this works below:

```js
var obj = {"data": [{"student_id": "bobby", "solved": 19}, {"student_id": "smith", "solved": 18}]};
             
console.log('Raw Data: ', obj.data);

var sorted = obj.data.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.solved-b.solved;
    });

console.log('Sorted: ', sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep all the data sorted and kept in a single array, you could create an object and put that into the array by doing something like this in the for loop:

```
    newData.push({
        student_id: data['data'][i].student_id,
        solved: data['data'][i].solved
    });
```

And when you go to sort it, you just need to change the sort function to do:

```
    newData.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.solved - b.solved;        
    });
```

When you go to access the array later instead of using, for example, `newData[3]`, just change the line to `newData[3].solved` or `newData[3]['solved']`.

Keeping your data in a single array like this will help make it easier to keep your `student_id` and `solved` values paired with each other. When you use multiple arrays, it is easier to have your indices mismatch with each other. But there's nothing stopping you from using more than one.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use "lodash" or "underscore" to sort your data by "solved",
in just one line of code:

```js
var data = {"data": [{"student_id": "bobby", "solved": 19}, {"student_id": "smith", "solved": 20}]}
var sorted = _.sortBy(data["data"],['solved']);
```

see https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy

Answer (score 1):

With small reusable one-liners

```js
const {data} = {"data": [
    {"student_id": "bobby", "solved": 19},
    {"student_id": "smith", "solved": 20}
]};

const sortBy = (by,arr) => arr.slice().sort((a,b) => b[by] - a[by]);
const getProp = (prop,obj) => obj[prop];

const sortById = sortBy.bind(null, 'student_id');
const sortBySolved = sortBy.bind(null, 'solved');

const getId = getProp.bind(null, 'student_id');
const getSolved = getProp.bind(null, 'solved');

const sortedIds = sortById(data).map(getId);
const sortedSolutions = sortBySolved(data).map(getSolved);

console.log(sortedIds);
console.log(sortedSolutions);
```